Regex to replace the last three octets of a mac address with XX:XX:XX and retain the first three?
I have found a solution on stackoverflow to replace ALL the 6 Octets of a MAC address with XX.
I use this when I post router logs, for privacy reasons.
It uses 's/([0-9a-eA-E]{2}:){5}[0-9a-eA-E]{2}/XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX/g'
or a simplified version
's/..:..:..:..:..:../XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX/g'

However to help troubleshoot specific devices I would like to retain the FIRST 3 Octets of the MAC address and replace only the LAST 3 Octets with XX e.g.
AA:22:CC:44:DD:66 becomes AA:22:CC:XX:XX:XX
I tried to delve into regex but the pattern matching for the replace element is pretty tough.
I tried a simple:
s/..:..:..:/XX:XX:XX:/g which to my surprise actually works but seems more by good luck than by design and I am not sure if there is anything which would trip it up.
If there was a similar solution for the (first) more robust expression above that would be useful.
Secondly, I noticed that the first (more rigorous) expression above:
's/([0-9a-eA-E]{2}:){5}[0-9a-eA-E]{2}/XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX/g'
Works on AA:22:CC:DD:EE:66
but does not work on AA:22:CC:DD:EE:FF
What needs to be changed, so as to work on ANY MAC address?
Note this is not a JavaScript related query and my problem differs markedly from the supposedly similar thread in that my question is for a problem based on a repeating pattern of 6 Octets (a MAC Address) and not just the last 4 words in a string.

If these are part of some larger text, try e.g. like this demo (regex101). It checks for all 6 parts but captures the first three to $1 (to insert in replacment) and replaces the latter with XX:XX:XX.

You can replace matches of the regular expression here with "XX:XX:XX". It employs a positive lookbehind (that begins with a negative lookbehind) and a negative lookahead. I've written the regular expression in extended (a.k.a free-spacing) mode to make it self-documenting.

Both work well thanks. Cary, I put your solution on a single line i.e. FIND: (?<=(?<!:)(?:[[:xdigit:]]{2}:){3})(?:[[:xdigit:]]{2}:){2}[[:xdigit:]]{2}(?!:)
REPLACE: XX:XX:XX

You may make use of the $ end marker in your regex pattern:
Find:    [A-Fa-f0-9]{2}(?::[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}){2}$
Replace: XX:XX:XX

Demo
Also note that the allowed values are 0-9 and a-f (case insensitive), not a-e.

I tried Tim's solution using the "are part of some larger text" example referred to bobble bubble but it did not seem to work? See https://regex101.com/r/xLj07p/2 bobble bubble solution seemed robust.

My solution should be just fine for JavaScript regex.  If you feel you need boundary markers, then add them...but you probably don't need them.

if you had to add boundary markers to your solution such that it worked with the test strings in bobble bubble's solution, what would that look like please? I tried to see if I could add his boundary markers but it dd not work.

Well you could try matching on \b[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}(?::[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}){2}$

That doesn't seem to work with the test strings, sorry https://regex101.com/r/xLj07p/3
